# Screen capture completes before I have selected area I want captured

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, screenshot

I'm a longtime Greenshot user and am familiar with how to use it. For the past month or longer, when I select the Print Screen button on my Windows 10 PC, I am able to start to do my capture but before I am done selecting a block of screen and before I let go of the mouse, the capture window opens (save, save as, etc).This is very frustrating!

I downloaded the latest version (which I believe I already had-1.2.10 Build 6(64 bit)) but I continue to have this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might try an alternative, e.g., https://alternativeto.net/software/greenshot/?platform=windows . Since I prefer to edit a full screenshot after the fact, in Paint or IrfanView, I can't help with the Greenshot issue.

Comment: Uninstall Greenshot. Restart. Run DISM / SFC and Restart again. Install Greenshot (latest) and test.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test. The run the PC manufacturer's Driver Update app.

Comment: Have you tried with a different mouse? There could be an issue with the button on yours.

Comment: Thanks all. I tried to follow John's suggestion but wasn't clear on how to run the DISM. Instead I uninstalled Greenshot, restarted and reinstalled it and I think it's working ok now. 

I think I may have not uninstalled before updating last time and this seemed to make a difference.